# Lifetime issue assigning reference from conditional

Tags: rust

I'm quite new in Rust and I'm having an issue with lifetimes that I believe I can understand what is happening and why, but can't get around in my head how can I solve it.

For simplicity I created this short "clone" of what I'm actually trying to do, but the real code is using [asyc-stripe](https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe). Will annotate the example code with the real one in case is relevant.

There is the following structure:

```rust
// https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe/blob/9f1a84144a23cc7b2124a1252ee15dc646ce0215/src/resources/generated/subscription.rs#L385
struct ObjectA<'a> {
    field: i32,
    object_b_id: Option<&'a str>,
}

// https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe/blob/9f1a84144a23cc7b2124a1252ee15dc646ce0215/src/resources/generated/subscription.rs#L570
impl<'a> ObjectA<'a> {
    fn new(field: i32) -> Self {
        return Self {
            field,
            object_b_id: Default::default(),
        };
    }
}

// https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe/blob/9f1a84144a23cc7b2124a1252ee15dc646ce0215/src/resources/generated/subscription.rs#L210
fn persist_obj_a(obj_a: ObjectA<'_>) {}

// ---

// https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe/blob/9f1a84144a23cc7b2124a1252ee15dc646ce0215/src/resources/generated/payment_method.rs#L18
struct ObjectB {
    id: ObjectBId,
}

// https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe/blob/9f1a84144a23cc7b2124a1252ee15dc646ce0215/src/ids.rs#L518
struct ObjectBId {
    value: String,
}

impl ObjectBId {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        return self.value.as_str();
    }
}

// This is a wrapper around https://github.com/arlyon/async-stripe/blob/9f1a84144a23cc7b2124a1252ee15dc646ce0215/src/resources/generated/payment_method.rs#L128 that just returns the first one found (id any, hence the Option)
fn load_object_b() -> Option<ObjectB> {
    return Some(ObjectB {
        id: ObjectBId {
            value: String::from("some_id"),
        },
    });
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is: load the `ObjectB` with `load_object_b` and use its ID into a `ObjectA`.

Ok, so on to my attempts.

#### First attempt

```rust
fn first_try(condition: bool) {
    let mut obj_a = ObjectA::new(1);

    if condition {
        match load_object_b() {
            Some(obj_b) => obj_a.object_b_id = Some(obj_b.id.as_str()),
            None => (),
        }
    }

    persist_obj_a(obj_a);
}
```

In here I get

> `obj_b.id` does not live long enough

Which I can understand, since from what I can understand the `obj_b` only exists during the match arm and is droped by the end of it.

#### Second attempt

```rust
fn second_try(condition: bool) {
    let mut obj_a = ObjectA::new(1);

    if condition {
        let obj_b = load_object_b();
        match obj_b {
            Some(ref obj_b) => obj_a.object_b_id = Some(obj_b.id.as_str()),
            None => (),
        }
    }

    persist_obj_a(obj_a);
}
```

Here I get

> `obj_b.0` does not live long enough

Which I guess it is still the same idea, just in a different place. Since again, from my understanding, `obj_b` now only lives within the scope of the `if` condition.

#### Third and last attempt

I ended up "solving" it with:

```rust
fn third_try(condition: bool) {
    let mut obj_a = ObjectA::new(1);

    let obj_b = load_object_b();
    let obj_b_id = match obj_b {
        Some(ref obj_b) => Some(obj_b.id.as_str()),
        None => None,
    };

    if condition {
        obj_a.object_b_id = obj_b_id;
    }

    persist_obj_a(obj_a);
}
```

In here I moved the `obj_b` to have the same lifetime as `obj_a`. So it solves the issue that I was having.
My problem with this solution is that I feel that I'm wasting resource doing the (possible expensive) request to `load_object_b` even if I'm not gonna use it based on the `condition`.
Not sure if I'm missing something very obvious or just going on the overall wrong direction, but would appreciate some light on what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, I think:

```
fn third_try(condition: bool) {
    let mut obj_a = ObjectA::new(1);

    let obj_b = if condition { load_object_b() } else { None };
    obj_a.object_b_id = obj_b.as_ref().map (|o| o.id.as_str());

    persist_obj_a(obj_a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rust allows you to have conditionally initialized variables. You can declare `obj_b` ouside of the `if`, but only initialize it inside the `if`. The compiler will ensure you can use it only if it is initialized.

```rust
fn second_try(condition: bool) {
    let mut obj_a = ObjectA::new(1);

    let obj_b;
    if condition {
        obj_b = load_object_b();
        match obj_b {
            Some(ref obj_b) => obj_a.object_b_id = Some(obj_b.id.as_str()),
            None => (),
        }
    }

    persist_obj_a(obj_a);
}
```